# Why can not I check my field via org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty? in simple java-class

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have in my rest-application method:

```
@GET
@Path("/myList")
 public MyList getMyList(...) {
 ...
  object_of_MyClass.myMethod();//go to method "myMethod()"
}
```

And java-class with method "myMethod()":

```
public class MyClass {

    @NotEmpty //Why it is not checked???
    @HeaderParam("myHeader") //this work (@HeaderParam inject "myHeader" always correctly)
    String valueHeader;

    public void myMethod() {
        //I want use here field valueHeader,
// but if valueHeader=null or empty I want throw Exception via @NotEmpty.
    } 
}
```

Why it is not checked via org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty?, Help me, please!

If I do check @NotEmpty in rest-class - all good, But I need do check in MyClass.java

Comment: Have a look in the documentation https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#validator-usingvalidator-validate . There is an example in 2.2.2.1

Comment: Thank you!, but Why Can not I use annotation @NotEmpty?

Comment: OK - I think you have not read the documentation. See my answer. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class MyClass {

    @NotEmpty(message = "This should never happen") //Why it is not checked???
    String valueHeader;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.myMethod();
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<MyClass>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(this);
        // Here we check if any validation error has occured
        if (constraintViolations.size() > 0) {
            for (ConstraintViolation<MyClass> error : constraintViolations) {
                System.out.println("The validation say: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```